# How to delete rich text by tag

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way to write a macro that deletes all rich text content control along with the text inside it that doesn't contain the word "Me" in it?

Similarly, rich text that is tagged like in this example:

> Assistant 1 and Me

would not be deleted either, since "Me" is listed in the tag.

This code is pretty close:

```vb
Sub DeleteRichTextControlNotContainingMe() 
Dim control As ContentControl 
' Loop through all content controls in the active document 
For Each control In ActiveDocument.ContentControls 
' Check if it's a rich text content control and if its tag does not contain "Me" 
   If control.Type = wdContentControlRichText And InStr(1, control.tag, "Me") = 0 Then 
' Delete the content control and its contents 
     control.Range.Text = "" 
     control.Delete 
   End If 
Next control 
End Sub
```

It deletes both the rich text content control and its internal text from all content control boxes that have a tag not containing "Me" anywhere in it.

The problem is that it's deleting the text inside the rich text content control boxes that **do** contain "Me" in the tag. However, it's retaining the tag itself.

Comment: Yes there is a way to do this. But it's highly dependent on your document and the content and how you want the macro to be started, etc. This is not a code writing service, so we can help if you show us what code you've tried and the problems you're having. As a word of advice, break your problem into tiny baby-step parts and write the code for that part first. Then slowly build up your solution. That's how it works.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT !This code is pretty close. It deletes the rich text content control and the text inside the rich text content control of all rich text content control boxes that have a tag not containing "Me" anywhere in it

The problem is that it's deleting the text inside the rich text content control boxes that DO contain "Me" somewhere in the tag. However, it's retaining the tag itself. Ive included the code below:

Comment: Sub DeleteRichTextControlNotContainingMe()
    Dim control As ContentControl
    
    ' Loop through all content controls in the active document
    For Each control In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        ' Check if it's a rich text content control and if its tag does not contain "Me"
        If control.Type = wdContentControlRichText And InStr(1, control.tag, "Me") = 0 Then
            ' Delete the content control and its contents
            control.Range.Text = ""
            control.Delete
        End If
    Next control
End Sub

Comment: @ayejay921 please don't post code in the comments. Edit your question instead and include the code and describe what is not working.

Comment: Sorry @Shrotter I'm new to this forum. I just edited my original post. Let me know if that's better

Comment: @ayejay921 your code checks only the value of the tag. So include there also a check for the text e.g.  `InStr(control.Range.Text, "Me")`